# Has anyone made quadcopter supporting ROS?

Tags: ros, quadcopter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am planning to build a quadcopter using ROS. A real one, NOT A SIMULATION.

I would like to know if there are any existing packages or tutorials that would help me do so.
I want it to be something like mobile robots: like follows config of REP 105 and works when I publish velocity commands on the topic cmd_vel (works with move_base).

Thanks in Advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277539/has-anyone-made-quadcopter-supporting-ros?/) by [Cobalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/31774/cobalt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several ones. Check out http://robots.ros.org/category/aerial/

About your plan to use move_base: This is mainly targeted at 2D Navigation, so I don't think this is the best way to go...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0